# How to resolve "serializes to the same string" message with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

In my React app, I've built a function that accepts a string full of regular text and any number of URLs.  It then converts these into a `<span>` in React with every URL inside of an `<a href` tag.  The code works really well but I can't seem to write a Jest test for it.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
expect(convertHyperlinks('http://stackoverflow.com'))
  .toStrictEqual(<span><a href='http://stackoverflow.com' target='_blank'>stackoverflow.com</a></span>);
```

And:

```
expect(convertHyperlinks('http://stackoverflow.com'))
  .toMatchInlineSnapshot(<span><a href='http://stackoverflow.com' target='_blank'>stackoverflow.com</a></span>);
```

In the former case I'm getting the "serializes to the same string" message.

In the latter case, it's showing me this:

```
Expected properties: <span><a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">stackoverflow.com</a></span>
Received value:      <span><a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">stackoverflow.com</a></span>
```

Might anyone know how to build a passing test for this?

Robert

Update: Here's the code for the function in question:

```
export const convertHyperlinks = (text: string): React.Node => {
  // Find all http instances
  const regex = /http\S*/g;
  const hyperlinkInstances = text.match(regex);

  if (!hyperlinkInstances) {
    return <span>{text}</span>;
  }

  // Break up `text` into its logical chunks of strings and hyperlinks
  let items = [];
  let idx1 = 0;
  let idx2 = -1;

  hyperlinkInstances.forEach((hyperlink) => {
    idx2 = text.indexOf(hyperlink, idx1);
    if (idx2 === idx1) {
      items.push(hyperlink);
      idx1 += hyperlink.length;
    } else {
      items.push(text.substring(idx1, idx2));
      items.push(hyperlink);
      idx1 = idx2 + hyperlink.length;
    }
  });

  if (idx1 < text.length) {
    items.push(text.substring(idx1, text.length));
  }

  return (
    <span>
      {items.map((item) => {
        if (item.includes('http://')) {
          const plainLink = item.replace('http://', '');
          return (
            <a href={item.toLowerCase()} target='_blank' key={plainLink}>
              {plainLink}
            </a>
          );
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      })}
    </span>
  );
};
```

Comment: Could you also post the code for `convertHyperlinks`?

Comment: @EmmanuelPonnudurai I just updated the post with the function code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a `ReactNode` from the method, which is an object. But you are trying to assert as just a string. It would'nt work.

This is what you may be getting back from the method,
[image]

And so, you must assert against the object you got, and not the way you are doing it right now,

```
const result = convertHyperlinks('http://stackoverflow.com')
expect(result.props[0].key).equals('stackoverflow.com');
// similar kind of assertions.
```

Additionally, I would suggest you go the component route and just render the component in the test method and assert for presence of elements as opposed to diving into react objects.

A representation of the same is as follows,

Here is your component,

```
const ConvertToHyperlinks = ({text}: {text: string}) => {
  // your logic and then returning DOM elements.
  return <></>;
}
```

Then you use it anywhere as,

```
<div>
  <ConvertToHyperlinks text={'https://www.test.com/'} />
</div>
```

In your unit test you can then,

```
const renderedComponent = render(<ConvertToHyperlinks text={''https://www.anytyhing.com}/>);
expect(renderdComponent.getByText('anytyhing.com')).ToBeInTheDocument();
```

Here I am using some Rect Testing Library method but the idea is same even if you use enzyme etc.

Comment: Thank you for this, @Emmanuel.  Ultimately this is not the "comprehensive" testing approach I assumed was possible but it is likely as effective as possible.  Much appreciated!